# Other than an interview question when would 'readonly ref readonly` be used in C#?

Tags: c#

I've just been told that `readonly ref readonly` is now valid C#, I can clearly see its use as an interview question, but otherwise when is it of real-life use?

Comment: could you show some (interview) code which uses `readonly ref readonly`?

Comment: @jamiec Saw a tweet from Jared Parsons admitting to enabling it.

Answer (score 7):

When you have a mutable struct in which you want to have a field `ref readonly` (a value you get by reference that cannot be modified by the caller) that does not mutate the struct.

You can find quite a good explanation here: ["Readonly Ref vs Ref Readonly in C# Struct"](https://medium.com/@simonas.baltulionis/readonly-ref-vs-ref-readonly-in-c-struct-75968f01508d)

> [image]

Now, as to "real-life" use cases... that's probably for performance-sensitive code, where copying the struct is too expensive.

---

Also, it's not really "new", it's possible to do this since C# 7.2: [Microsoft Docs | Readonly references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref#motivation)